# Bundling QuillJs with Webpack Cause Error

Tags: webpack

I am trying to import QuillJs to my project. I have been following all their documentation but there is error. I do not miss any single step.

I did an instalation by using npm

> npm install quill@1.3.6

then put the import code into my main.js & bundling with webpack

```
import Quill from 'quill/core';

import Toolbar from 'quill/modules/toolbar';
import Snow from 'quill/themes/snow';

import Bold from 'quill/formats/bold';
import Italic from 'quill/formats/italic';
import Header from 'quill/formats/header';

Quill.register({
  'modules/toolbar': Toolbar,
  'themes/snow': Snow,
  'formats/bold': Bold,
  'formats/italic': Italic,
  'formats/header': Header
});

export default Quill;
```

However, I receive this following error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/quill/assets/icons/image.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <svg viewbox="0 0 18 18">
|   <rect class="ql-stroke" height="10" width="12" x="3" y="4"></rect>
|   <circle class="ql-fill" cx="6" cy="7" r="1"></circle>
 @ ./node_modules/quill/ui/icons.js 31:16-52
 @ ./node_modules/quill/themes/snow.js
 @ ./main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/quill/assets/icons/video.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <svg viewbox="0 0 18 18">
|   <rect class="ql-stroke" height="12" width="12" x="3" y="3"></rect>
|   <rect class="ql-fill" height="12" width="1" x="5" y="3"></rect>
 @ ./node_modules/quill/ui/icons.js 48:16-52
 @ ./node_modules/quill/themes/snow.js
 @ ./main.js
```

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently
>   no loaders are configured to process this file.

I have installed all the required dependencies

> babel-core, babel-loader, babel-preset-es2015, ts-loader, css-loader, typescript,
>   html-loader

However, i still got the error, no idea why.I really appreciate any answer. Here is the official guide
https://quilljs.com/guides/adding-quill-to-your-build-pipeline/

Answer (score 1):

You need to install and configure a loader to handle SVG files or other images:

```
npm install file-loader --save-dev
```

Then, in your Webpack configuration (`webpack.config.js`):

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```